# How to Bind Images in Gridview all cells dynamically & get values from cell

Tags: gridview, cell, dynamic

I am developing movie theater seat booking website like http://in.bookmyshow.com/, for that i have place image as Seats in asp:gridview(all cells), for selection of seat click on Image(cell) at that time i need that cell value(Seat No) where i clicked Image(cell) in gridview. This binding based on Database In Database Cell value=0 Then in gridviewCell no image In Database Cell value=1 Then in gridviewCell image indicate available Seat In Database Cell value=2 Then in gridviewCell image indicate Selected Seat In Database Cell value=3 Then in gridviewCell image indicate Booked Seat This Database is every time changes by selecting deferent Theater. So theater layout is not fix to some Rows & Columns, so this all binding is done dynamically. If possible send me Sample code. Please help me.